# Python writing to text file and avoiding duplicate values

Tags: python, text-files

I'm currently having difficulties saving hashes to a txt file.

I am getting a hash from each image I download from reddit, and I am wishing to store this hash into a txt file if its not in the txt file already.

If the hash of the image is already in the txt file, it wont post it in the txt file again (no duplicate hashes) and it will delete the image.

However, i am having difficulty doing this, as it adds the same hash multiple times.

```
def checkImage():
database_file = "hash_database.txt"


for filename in os.listdir('NewImages//'):
    upload = file_path + '\\' + filename

# Get hash of each image
for filename in os.listdir('NewImages//'):
    new_images = imagehash.phash(Image.open('NewImages//' + filename))

    with open(database_file, "r") as f:
        read_database = f.readlines()
    for line in read_database:
        if line == str(new_images):
            print("Delete this image, hash is already in database")
            os.remove(upload)
        else:
            print("Save this image. Adding hash to database")
            with open(database_file, "a") as f:
                f.write(str(new_images) + "\n")
```

checkImage():

Picture of my database: [image]
As you can see, there are multiple of the same hashes.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line` has a newline `\n` at the end, so you're comparing `"abcde"` to `"abcde\n"`, which aren't equal.

You can use `.strip()` to remove the newline:

```
for line in read_database:
    line = line.strip()
    if line == str(new_images):
        ...
```

UPDATE:

Also, the logic for the `else` block is wrong.  You're treating the hash as new if it doesn't match the *current* line in the file, but you should do that only if it doesn't match *any* line in the file.

Comment: Thanks for replying, however it still seems to do the same thing.

Comment: I added another part to my answer.

Comment: Alright, thanks John. Ill have a look into the else block now :)

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean about the else block. How would I go about seeing if its in ANY line in the file?

Comment: Thanks, figured it out. Legend!